# From Python, piping images to FFMPEG process with audio input, "-shortest" flag causes output file to contain only 1 frame of video and entire audio

Tags: python, ffmpeg, pipe, video-processing

From Python, I run FFMPEG and write images to its stdin via pipe, the FFMPEG process has an audio file as input too. Everything works fine like this:

```
cmd = ['ffmpeg', '-hide_banner', '-y', '-loglevel', 'error', '-f', 'rawvideo', 
'-pix_fmt', 'bgr24', '-video_size', '720x1280', '-r', '30.0', '-an', '-i', '-',
'-i', 'audio.aac', '-acodec', 'copy', 
'-crf', '14', '-pix_fmt', 'yuv420p', 'output.mp4']
proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, **popen_params)
```

Because the audio duration might be longer than the video duration, I added a '-shortest' flag (before '-crf'):

```
cmd = ['ffmpeg', '-hide_banner', '-y', '-loglevel', 'error', '-f', 'rawvideo', 
'-pix_fmt', 'bgr24', '-video_size', '720x1280', '-r', '30.0', '-an', '-i', '-',
'-i', 'audio.aac', '-acodec', 'copy', 
'-shortest', '-crf', '14', '-pix_fmt', 'yuv420p', 'output.mp4']
proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, **popen_params)
```

However, with the '-shortest' flag, the resulting output.mp4 contains the entire audio, but only 1 frame of video data. What is going on here ?

Comment: Post a [mre] with debugging details.

Comment: Hi. Were you able to solve this issue? Would appreciate if you could share